# How would I extend my animation further? (animate.css)

Tags: html, css, wave, animate.css

Essentially I have a wave animated using animate.css which I am trying to extend the (svg image) further beyond the border of the website so that there isn't a strange gap while it's animating (i hope that makes sense). Please check the attached image.

[image: Wave]

HTML

```
<div class="top">

    <h1></h1>

</div>

<div class="wave animated pulse">

    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="image/svg1wave.svg">
        <!-- fallback -->
        <img src="image/svg1wave.svg" alt="wave-front">
    </object>

</div>

    <div class="wave2 animated pulse">

  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="image/svg2wave.svg">
        <!-- fallback -->
        <img src="image/svg2wave.svg" alt="wave-front">
    </object>

   </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
width: auto;
background-color: #61d4f4;
```

}

```
.top {
background: white;
```

}

```
.wave {
margin: 500px auto 0 auto;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
width:100%;
```

}

```
.wave2 {
margin: -50px auto 0 auto;
-webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
position:relative;
```

}

Comment: Make `.wave` class width more then 100% and hide the `overflow` on container class.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be a bother but I'm slightly unsure by the "hide the overflow on container class" the overflow I have is already set to "overflow-x: hidden;" could you clarify please? thank you.

Comment: Managed to get it fixed using: position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    float: right;